# Convert command for EPS to JPG

Tags: unix, command, cygwin

I want to know how to use convert command to convert `EPS` img to `JPG`.

I dont have Linux M/c but I am using Cygwin. I have searched, but nothing is working. I always get invalid argument error.

```
$ convert "/cygdrive/e/pdf/B313.eps" "/cygdrive/e/macro/B313.JPG"
Invalid Parameter - /e
```

It will be great if could solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot test it for cygwin but the following is working under unix:

```
convert -density 50 -antialias -colors 128 -background white -normalize -units PixelsPerInch -quality 100 /path/to/eps/test.eps test.jpg
```

Maybe you have to use backslashes for the file path under windows

```
$ convert "\cygdrive\e\pdf\B313.eps" "\cygdrive\e\macro\B313.JPG"
```

And try it with absolute paths like c:\path\ ...
Keep in mind that there's another convert command under windows which converts between file systems. Maybe the wrong one is being invoked.

Comment: Thanks a lot, But its not working in Cygwin. I used the exactly same format, I guess it not path issue.                                   $ convert -density 50 -antialias -colors 128 -background white -normalize -units PixelsPerInch -quality 100 "\cygdrive\e\pdf\B313.pdf" "i.jpg"
Invalid Parameter - 50

Comment: Finally I got the working solution. First I installed the imagemagic and then ghostscript. Then convert.exe command is working fine. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear you could fix it.